# Data pass using screen in body part

Tags: php, mysql, fedora, asterisk

I have an issue with this. I pass the data using screen and generate email and that string format is something like this.

```
/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/scllevel/email.php  '20' '2012-08-08 12:00:43'   'bhavik.patel@gmail.com' 'For Less Attendances'  '"<p>\r\n\tFor late Coming<\/p>\r\n1111111111111111\r\ntesting this is testing's this is \"Testing\"\r\n"' '178' '22' 'info@broadcast.com'
```

I have a problem like in single quotation the body part is not proper set and they behave as a different command my body part start from

```
"<p>['\r\n\tFor late Coming<\/p>\r\n1111111111111111\r\ntesting this is testing's this is \"Testing\"\r\n"]
```

If any of the user body is something like this, then problem will be created so is there any idea about this. I already used PHP functions like  htmlentities, addcslashes and stripslashes but in vain.

Comment: Did you try `escapeshellarg`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php

Comment: Yes i already try this one.........

Comment: Could you perhaps share the PHP code you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you want to remove slashes. Your php gets the mail in slashed strings, what you need to do is to use "`stripslashes`" to convert the slashed strings to its not-slashed form, e.g.

you need to simply convert "`\r`" -s to `0x10` -s in the string ASCII representation.

`htmlentities` and the other functions are unneeded for this simple task.

If it won't be enough, paste your email.php here and I will check this.